# Debian wrong login and TTY resolution on 4K screen

Tags: debian, resolution, tty

I have just installed Debian MATE Jessie on a laptop that has a 4K screen resolution, which by default sets the resolution to 3840x2160. I've been able to change the GRUB resolution to 1280x1024 using `GRUB_GFXMODE` but the greeter screen and the TTYs will always use the default resolution. I've unsuccessfully tried using `GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep` or setting it to the same value as `GRUB_GFXMODE`.

I'm running with an Intel graphics card, no Nvidia or Radeon. I've also tried to set it using `xrandr` although I get a `Can't open display` error.

How can I set a more reasonable resolution (i.e. 1280x1024 or similar)?

Available resolutions:

```
$ sudo hwinfo --framebuffer

02: None 00.0: 11001 VESA Framebuffer                           
  [Created at bios.459]
  Unique ID: rdCR.QstqgPARaQB
  Hardware Class: framebuffer
  Model: ""
  Vendor: ""
  Device: ""
  SubVendor: "Intel(R) HSW Mobile/Desktop Graphics Chipset Accelerated VGA BIOS"
  SubDevice: 
  Revision: ""
  Memory Size: 31 MB + 960 kB
  Memory Range: 0xd0000000-0xd1feffff (rw)
  Mode 0x033c: 1920x1440 (+1920), 8 bits
  Mode 0x034d: 1920x1440 (+3840), 16 bits
  Mode 0x035c: 1920x1440 (+7680), 24 bits
  Mode 0x033a: 1600x1200 (+1600), 8 bits
  Mode 0x034b: 1600x1200 (+3200), 16 bits
  Mode 0x035a: 1600x1200 (+6400), 24 bits
  Mode 0x0307: 1280x1024 (+1280), 8 bits
  Mode 0x031a: 1280x1024 (+2560), 16 bits
  Mode 0x031b: 1280x1024 (+5120), 24 bits
  Mode 0x0305: 1024x768 (+1024), 8 bits
  Mode 0x0317: 1024x768 (+2048), 16 bits
  Mode 0x0318: 1024x768 (+4096), 24 bits
  Mode 0x0312: 640x480 (+2560), 24 bits
  Mode 0x0314: 800x600 (+1600), 16 bits
  Mode 0x0315: 800x600 (+3200), 24 bits
  Mode 0x0301: 640x480 (+640), 8 bits
  Mode 0x0303: 800x600 (+832), 8 bits
  Mode 0x0311: 640x480 (+1280), 16 bits
  Mode 0x037d: 3840x2160 (+3840), 8 bits
  Mode 0x037e: 3840x2160 (+7680), 16 bits
  Mode 0x037f: 3840x2160 (+15360), 24 bits
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
```